# QGIS transparent layers plot as solid opaque - solution?

Tags: qgis, plot

I have been trying to plot from QGIS to a HP Designjet T120 plotter using Win10x64, but the transparent layers of my QGIS project appear as solid opaque on the plot.

If I plot to PDF to transparent layer are transparent.

Is my problem with the HP plotter driver settings do you think?

I cannot see where to change this on the plotter configuration settings.

Comment: What happens if you output to PDF, then send the PDF to the plotter (outside of QGIS)?

Comment: Yes, that's OK thanks. It just means I need to take two processes to print, i.e first PDF then PDF to printer, so was wondering how to do directly from QGIS to printer.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as off topic, seems like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 0):

try saving and printing it as png.